# UILabel text scaling, Programmatically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to change my `UILabel` text **or** `UILabel` itself's size by using `UISlider`, I know it's something we don't do it for an normal application. But basically I am trying new and different things to explore Objective -C language and iOS platform.

So far I am able to change colour of a font by `UISlider`, Which looks really great, So thought of changing it's size too by `UISlider`. Below I am posting pictures to clarify my thoughts visually!

**From** -----> 
[image]
**To** ------->
[image]

While making those images I realised I might have to change size of `UILable` and Size of font too. Am I right? Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:slider.value];    
CGSize newSize = [textLabel.text sizeWithFont:textLabel.font];
```

This should make it
an alternative is to set the fram of the label above the complete size above the textField and set `textAlignement = center`

Answer (score 1):

its quite simple actually

According to slider change value dynamically increase height and width of your label..

Answer (score 1):

There can be many ways you can handle this, one way would be to just change the font size with slider and when you change the font calculate the frame size with sizeWithFont: instance method of NSString.